# Run Elastic Search on pdf and ppts

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-tika

I am new to elastic search. I have read its tutorials. But need guidance on my problem:

I have a collection of pdf documents and power point files on my system. I need to build a system using elastic search where I can retrieve these files on the basis of keywords present in this file. Can someone please guide as to how can I proceed here and index my documents.Do I need to parse my pdf and convert it to JSON format using Tika or FSCrawler and then provide it to elastic search.

Thankyou.

Comment: Here is an answer to the same problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48065342/how-to-use-elasticsearch-to-make-files-in-a-directory-searchable/48067577#48067577

Comment: Here is an answer to the same problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48065342/how-to-use-elasticsearch-to-make-files-in-a-directory-searchable/48067577#48067577

Answer (score 1):

You should setup FSCrawler, that'll do the parsing and make the files content searchable.