# How to use Elasticsearch to make files in a directory searchable?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I am very new to search engines and Elasticsearch, so please bear with me and apologies if this question sounds vague. I have a large directory with lots of .csv and .hdr files, and I want to be able to search text within these files. I've done the tutorials and read some of the documentation but I'm still struggling to understand the concept of indexing. It seems like all the tutorials show you how to index one document at a time, but this will take a long time as I have lots of files. Is there an easier way to make elasticsearch index all the documents in this directory and be able to search for what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch can only search on documents it has *indexed*. *Indexed* means Elasticsearch has *consumed* a document one by one and stored it internally.

Normaly internal structure matters and you shold understand what you're doing to get best performance.

So you need a way to get your files into elastic search, I'm affraid there is no "one click way" to achieve this...

You need

1. Running cluster
2. Designed index on for the documents
3. Get document from filesystem to Elasticsearch

Your question is focused on 3).

For this, search for script examples or tools that can crawl your directory and provide Elasticsearch with documents.

5 seconds of using Google brought me to

- https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler
- https://gist.github.com/stevehanson/7462063
- Theoretically it could be done with Logstash (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html), but I would give fscrawler a try.

Comment: I think my question was a little unclear. I was hoping Elasticsearch had something similar to what solr has: "C:\solr-7.2.0> java -jar -Dc=techproducts -Dauto example\exampledocs\post.jar example\exampledocs\*". This indexes all data in a directory. Thank you for your answer though, it was still helpful.

Comment: Elastic Filebeat wouuld be another way to index all files in a given directory.